# How to add the dynamic pivot table columns in apex interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to add dynamic pivot columns in the APEX interactive grid query?

PL/SQL function body returning SQL query:

```
DECLARE
  
  l_piv_col VARCHAR2(1000) := NVL(:P1_DEP_PIVOT,'10 DEP1');
  l_statement VARCHAR2(4000):= 
 q'~
select rownum row_num,JOB,MGR,DEP1,DEP2,DEP3 
from
(select JOB,
       MGR,
       SAL,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP
)
src 
--PIVOT (sum(sal) for deptno IN (10 DEP1,20 DEP2,null DEP3)) Piv 
PIVOT (sum(sal) for deptno IN (##PIV_COL##)) Piv 
~';
BEGIN

  RETURN REPLACE(l_statement,'##PIV_COL##',l_piv_col);
  --RETURN l_statement;
END;
```

P1_DEP_PIVOT -> (10 DEP1, 20 DEP2, null DEP3)

In the pivot deptno in, I need to use the dynamic columns.

sum(sal) for deptno IN (##PIV_COL##)

I am not sure, how to add the dynamic pivot columns in APEX Interactive grid?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the reproducible case.
Classic Report is the only APEX Component which supports the query returning a changing set of result columns. Interactive Reports and Interactive Grid do not support this.

In classic report, pick the region source as PL/SQL function body returning SQL query and enable the Generic Columns switch. Then configure the maximum amount of columns, and you're good to go.

There are a couple of workarounds that I can think of if you really need an interactive grid (IG).

- Store the results of the query in a collection, create an IG on top of the collection and have a server side condition to hide the columns that should not be displayed
- Make sure your query always returns a fixed number of columns and have page item (to manage hide/show) for each of the columns. If a column should not be in the pivot, hide it based on the page item.