# How to adjust SQL to sort columns by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle Apex 23.2 on an Oracle 21.c database.

I have an app that tracks attendance for events using three tables.

**VOL_ATTENDANCE**

| Prim_Key | Event_Fkey | Contact_Fkey | Attendance-Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 258 | In-Person |
| 2 | 1 | 801 | In-Person |
| 3 | 1 | 234 | Zoom |
| 4 | 2 | 258 | In-Person |
| 5 | 2 | 234 | Zoom |

**VOL_CONTACT**

| Prim_Key | Last_Name | First_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | Potter | Harry |
| 258 | Weasley | Ron |
| 801 | Granger | Hermione |
| 500 | Weasley | Ginny |

**VOL_EVENT**

| Prim_Key | Event_Name | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meeting | 30-MAR-23 |
| 2 | Meeting | 18-APR-23 |

I'd like to get a report in the following format (Rows by last name, Columns by date, and using “I” and “Z” for In-Person and Zoom):

**DESIRED REPORT**

|  | Mar 30, 2023 | Apr 18, 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hermione Granger | I |  |
| Harry Potter | Z | Z |
| Ginny Weasley |  |  |
| Ron Weasley | I | I |

If I run the following SQL I get a standard tabular report:

```
Select
   vc.first_name
 , vc.last_name
 , va.attendance_type
 , ve.event_date
From
   VOL_CONTACT vc
 , VOL_EVENT ve
 , VOL_ATTENDANCE va
Where
   va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key
And va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key
Order by
   ve.event_date desc
 , vc.last_name
 , vc.first_name;
```

I don't know how to adjust the SQL (or PL/SQL) to obtain the DESIRED REPORT described above.

Comment: SQL select statement can give you static list of columns. So your `event_date` column has only two records or there can be multiple records? If multiple records then you can go ahead with dynamic sql in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  There will be more than two columns.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer(s) you probably need to use PIVOT and dynamic SQL. You should also learn to use the ANSI SQL join syntax which is easier to read, write and change. The join syntax you are using hasn't been good practice for 30+ years

Comment: [**Bad habits to kick** : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: In my opinion you should just use the query you have and loop through these results in your app and care about the layout (one column per date) there.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL (not just Oracle), you need to know the number and identifiers for the columns when you use them in a query; therefore, Oracle does not support dynamic pivots.

If you have known, fixed dates which you want to pivot (such as `2023-03-30` and `2023-04-18`) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT vc.first_name || ' ' || vc.last_name AS name,
         SUBSTR(va.attendance_type, 1, 1) AS attendance_type,
         ve.event_date
  FROM   VOL_CONTACT vc
         INNER JOIN VOL_ATTENDANCE va
         ON (va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key)
         INNER JOIN VOL_EVENT ve
         ON (va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key)
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(attendance_type) FOR event_date IN (
    DATE '2023-03-30' AS "30 Mar, 2023",
    DATE '2023-04-18' AS "18 Apr, 2023"
  )
)
ORDER BY name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE VOL_CONTACT (Prim_Key, Last_Name, First_Name) AS
SELECT 234, 'Potter',  'Harry' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 258, 'Weasley', 'Ron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 801, 'Granger', 'Hermione' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500, 'Weasley', 'Ginny' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE VOL_EVENT (Prim_Key, Event_Name, Event_Date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Meeting', DATE '2023-03-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Meeting', DATE '2023-04-18' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE VOL_ATTENDANCE (Prim_Key, Event_Fkey, Contact_Fkey, Attendance_Type) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 258, 'In-Person' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 801, 'In-Person' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 234, 'Zoom' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 258, 'In-Person' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 234, 'Zoom' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | 30 Mar, 2023 | 18 Apr, 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Harry Potter | Z | Z |
| Hermione Granger | I | *null* |
| Ron Weasley | I | I |

---

If you do not know how many (or which) dates you are going to return then you are better returning the data as rows (rather than column):

```sql
SELECT vc.first_name || ' ' || vc.last_name AS name,
       SUBSTR(va.attendance_type, 1, 1) AS attendance_type,
       ve.event_date
FROM   VOL_CONTACT vc
       INNER JOIN VOL_ATTENDANCE va
       ON (va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key)
       INNER JOIN VOL_EVENT ve
       ON (va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key)
ORDER BY event_date, name
```

Which outputs:

| NAME | ATTENDANCE_TYPE | EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Harry Potter | Z | 2023-03-30 00:00:00 |
| Hermione Granger | I | 2023-03-30 00:00:00 |
| Ron Weasley | I | 2023-03-30 00:00:00 |
| Harry Potter | Z | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 |
| Ron Weasley | I | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 |

---

Otherwise you will need to try either:

- dynamic SQL or
- [transposing rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70030943/1509264) in an Oracle Apex Classic Report.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yn1flSR4)

Answer (score 0):

The first concept you need to apply is PIVOT [see Managing Pivot Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aeeug/managing-pivot-reports.html#GUID-5B3D9691-91D8-43F0-B43E-293070473CA5)

An example based on your data above (N.B. This is SQL not PL/SQL - sorry)

```
select 
     first_name
    ,last_name
    ,LEFT(isnull([30-MAR-23],''),1) AS [Mar 30, 2023]
    ,LEFT(isnull([18-APR-23],''),1) AS [Apr 18, 2023]
from
(
    Select
       vc.first_name
     , vc.last_name
     , va.attendance_type
     , ve.event_date
    From
       VOL_CONTACT vc
    left outer join
        VOL_ATTENDANCE va on va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key
    left outer join 
        VOL_EVENT ve on va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key
) src
PIVOT
(
    max(attendance_type) for event_date in ([30-MAR-23], [18-APR-23])
) pvt
order by 
    Last_Name
    ,First_Name;
```

However, this relies on you knowing the dates in `VOL_EVENT` when you write the SQL. So the next concept you need is "Dynamic SQL" or "Dynamic Queries" which I believe in Oracle is [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Comment: This is not valid Oracle SQL syntax as `LEFT` is not a valid Oracle function, `[]` brackets are invalid syntax and `''` is identical to `NULL`.

Comment: @MT0 - I did say "(N.B. This is SQL not PL/SQL - sorry)"

Comment: PL/SQL is not the same as Oracle's SQL dialect (and your answer is probably SQL Server's SQL dialect). PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language similar to SQL Server's TSQL or PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 0):

One a bit long code option, but fast and reliable, is to use [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) that alows you not to hard-code dates of events but, on the  other hand, requests that you define how many events you want to track. In this answer I put them 4 (there are 2 in sample data) and you can add it more if needed.

```sql
WITH    S a m p l e    D a t a :
    VOL_ATTENDANCE ( "PRIM_KEY", "EVENT_FKEY", "CONTACT_FKEY", "ATTENDANCE_TYPE" ) AS
        ( Select 1, 1,  258,    'In-Person' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1,  801,    'In-Person' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 1,  234,    'Zoom' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 2,  258,    'In-Person' From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 2,  234,    'Zoom' From Dual 
        ),
    VOL_CONTACT ( PRIM_KEY, LAST_NAME,  FIRST_NAME ) AS
        ( Select 234,   'Potter',   'Harry' From Dual Union All
          Select 258,   'Weasley',  'Ron' From Dual Union All
          Select 801,   'Granger',  'Hermione' From Dual Union All
          Select 500,   'Weasley',  'Ginny' From Dual 
        ),
    VOL_EVENT ( PRIM_KEY,   EVENT_NAME, EVENT_DATE ) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Meeting',  DATE '2023-03-30' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'Meeting',  DATE '2023-04-18' From Dual 
        ),
```

Now we need to create a cte that will prepare your data for modeling

```sql
  grid AS
    (  Select     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE) "RN", 
                  Case  When ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By c.PRIM_KEY Order By c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE) = 1 Then 1 End "RN_CONTACT",
                  '*' || LISTAGG(DISTINCT To_Char(e.EVENT_DATE, 'Mon dd, yyyy'), '*') WITHIN GROUP (Order By c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE) OVER(Partition By c.PRIM_KEY) || '*' "DTS",
                  '*' || LISTAGG(DISTINCT To_Char(e.EVENT_DATE, 'Mon dd, yyyy'), '*') WITHIN GROUP (Order By Nvl(e.EVENT_DATE, DATE '2062-10-11')) OVER() || '*' "ALL_DTS",
                  '*' || LISTAGG(SubStr(a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE, 1, 1), '*') WITHIN GROUP (Order By c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, Nvl(e.EVENT_DATE, DATE '2062-10-11')) OVER(Partition By c.PRIM_KEY) || '*' "TPS",
                  c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME,
                  e.EVENT_DATE, e.EVENT_NAME,
                  SubStr(a.ATTENDANCE_TYPE, 1, 1) "ATT_TP"
        From      VOL_CONTACT c
        Left Join VOL_ATTENDANCE a ON(a.CONTACT_FKEY = c.PRIM_KEY)
        Left Join VOL_EVENT e ON(e.PRIM_KEY = a.EVENT_FKEY)
        Order By  c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE
    )
```

Modeling:

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT   CONTACT, DT_1, DT_2, DT_3, DT_4
FROM    ( Select    CONTACT, RN,
                    ALL_DT_1, ALL_DT_2, ALL_DT_3, ALL_DT_4, 
                    Max(Case When ALL_DT_1 = DT_1 Or ALL_DT_1 = DT_2 Or ALL_DT_1 = DT_3 Or All_DT_1 = DT_4 Then ALL_DT_1 End) "DT_1", 
                    Max(Case When ALL_DT_2 = DT_1 Or ALL_DT_2 = DT_2 Or ALL_DT_2 = DT_3 Or All_DT_2 = DT_4 Then ALL_DT_2 End) "DT_2",
                    Max(Case When ALL_DT_3 = DT_1 Or ALL_DT_3 = DT_2 Or ALL_DT_3 = DT_3 Or All_DT_3 = DT_4 Then ALL_DT_3 End) "DT_3",
                    Max(Case When ALL_DT_4 = DT_1 Or ALL_DT_4 = DT_2 Or ALL_DT_4 = DT_3 Or All_DT_4 = DT_4 Then ALL_DT_4 End) "DT_4",
                    --
                    Max(TP_1) "TP_1", Max(TP_2) "TP_2", Max(TP_3) "TP_3", Max(TP_4) "TP_4",
                    Max(ATT_MASK) "ATT_MASK"
          From      ( Select  Sum(RN_CONTACT) OVER(Order By RN Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "RN", 
                              FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME "CONTACT", ALL_DTS, DTS,
                              --
                              SubStr(ALL_DTS, 2, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 2) - 2) "ALL_DT_1",
                              SubStr(ALL_DTS, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 3) - InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 2) - 1) "ALL_DT_2",
                              SubStr(ALL_DTS, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 3) + 1, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 4) - InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 3) - 1) "ALL_DT_3",
                              SubStr(ALL_DTS, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 4) + 1, InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 5) - InStr(ALL_DTS, '*', 1, 4) - 1) "ALL_DT_4",
                              --
                              SubStr(DTS, 2, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 2) - 2) "DT_1", 
                              SubStr(DTS, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 3) - InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 2) - 1) "DT_2",
                              SubStr(DTS, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 3) + 1, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 4) - InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 3) - 1) "DT_3",
                              SubStr(DTS, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 4) + 1, InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 5) - InStr(DTS, '*', 1, 4) - 1) "DT_4",
                              --
                              SubStr(TPS, 2, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 2) - 2) "TP_1", 
                              SubStr(TPS, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 3) - InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 2) - 1) "TP_2",
                              SubStr(TPS, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 3) + 1, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 4) - InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 3) - 1) "TP_3",
                              SubStr(TPS, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 4) + 1, InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 5) - InStr(TPS, '*', 1, 4) - 1) "TP_4",
                              Cast(Null As VarChar2(32)) "ATT_MASK"
                      From grid
                      Order By LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
                    ) 
GROUP BY CONTACT, RN, ALL_DT_1, ALL_DT_2, ALL_DT_3, ALL_DT_4
ORDER BY RN
)
      MODEL   Dimension By ( RN )
              Measures     ( CONTACT, ALL_DT_1, ALL_DT_2, ALL_DT_3, ALL_DT_4, 
                              DT_1, DT_2, DT_3, DT_4, TP_1, TP_2, TP_3, TP_4,
                              ATT_MASK)
      RULES   ( CONTACT[0] = Null,
                DT_1[0] = Max(ALL_DT_1)[RN > 0],
                DT_2[0] = Max(ALL_DT_2)[RN > 0],
                DT_3[0] = Max(ALL_DT_3)[RN > 0],
                DT_4[0] = Max(ALL_DT_4)[RN > 0],
                --
                ATT_MASK[RN > 0] = Case  When  DT_1[CV()] Is Not Null Then '1'  Else 'x' End ||
                                   Case  When  DT_2[CV()] Is Not Null Then SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 1) || '2' Else 'x' End ||
                                   Case  When  DT_3[CV()] Is Not Null Then SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 2) || '3' Else 'x' End ||
                                   Case  When  DT_4[CV()] Is Not Null Then SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 3) || '4' Else 'x' End,
                --
                DT_1[RN > 0] = Case When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 1) = '1' Then TP_1[CV()] End,
                DT_2[RN > 0] = Case When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 2) IN('12', 'x2') Then TP_2[CV()] End,
                DT_3[RN > 0] = Case When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 3, 1) = '3'  And 3 - Length(Replace(SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 3), 'x', '')) = 0 Then TP_3[CV()] 
                                    When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 3, 1) = '3'  And 3 - Length(Replace(SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 3), 'x', '')) = 1 Then TP_2[CV()]
                                    When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 3, 1) = '3'  And 3 - Length(Replace(SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 1, 3), 'x', '')) = 2 Then TP_1[CV()] End,
                DT_4[RN > 0] = Case When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 4) = '4'  And 4 - Length(Replace(ATT_MASK[CV()], 'x', '')) = 0 Then TP_4[CV()] 
                                    When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 4) = '4'  And 4 - Length(Replace(ATT_MASK[CV()], 'x', '')) = 1 Then TP_3[CV()]
                                    When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 4) = '4'  And 4 - Length(Replace(ATT_MASK[CV()], 'x', '')) = 2 Then TP_2[CV()]
                                    When SubStr(ATT_MASK[CV()], 4) = '4'  And 4 - Length(Replace(ATT_MASK[CV()], 'x', '')) = 3 Then TP_1[CV()] End
              )
Order By RN
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
CONTACT             DT_1            DT_2            DT_3            DT_4        
------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ------------------
                    Mar 30, 2023      Apr 18, 2023      
Hermione Granger    I           
Harry Potter        Z                 Z     
Ginny Weasley                                                                                       
Ron Weasley         I                 I                                                 */
```

It certainly looks complicated but it is not when you get into it. Most of the code is copy-pasted and corrected. And you can widen it if needed. Oracle processes the data in a way pretty similar to excel spreadsheet - it is all about addressing rows/columns/cells. See the docs for details.
If we add one more row in VOL_ATTENDANCE and another one in VOL_EVENT sample tables:

```sql
Select 6, 3,  500,    'In-Person' From Dual     -- VOL_ATTENDANCE
Select 3,   'Meeting',  DATE '2023-05-01' From Dual     -- VOL_EVENT
```

... without any code interventions there will be another event date fetched with it's contact and attendance type

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
CONTACT             DT_1            DT_2            DT_3            DT_4        
------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ------------------
                    Mar 30, 2023     Apr 18, 2023   May 01, 2023    
Hermione Granger    I           
Harry Potter        Z                Z      
Ginny Weasley                                       I   
Ron Weasley         I                I                                                    */
```

Below is Apex Classic Report:
[image]